# how can i predict with orange api in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orange

I am new using the orange api and I do not understand well what is required by the python code to achieve a prediction of the model of a neural network

```py
    import pickle
    import Orange

    #Load model
    with open("modelNN.pkcls", "rb") as f:
      model = pickle.load(f)

    data = Orange.data.Table('test.xlsx')
    model.predict(data[0])



Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[6.0000000e+00 2.0000000e+00 3.0000000e+00 3.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00
 2.0000000e+00 1.7283000e+02 1.7179000e+02 6.1008990e+05 1.9051511e+06
 1.1090000e+04 3.5300000e+03].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says `model.predict()` accepts a 2D array and it received a 1D array. If you print `data[0]`, you will see it is indeed 1D.

Documentation is poor on the subject of predictions, but here's how it works:

- `model.predict()` accepts a 2D numpy array
- `model.predict_storage()` accepts Orange.data.Table

model's `__call__` function tries to intelligently handle the input, which means you can do
`model(data[0])` with data being either of type `numpy.array` or `Orange.data.Table`.

That said, Orange is not really intended to be used as a library. I would suggest using it via GUI or rather using other Python libraries, such as sklearn, on which Orange is based anyway.